# ASP.Net How can I iterate all rows in grid using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am having trouble in calculation in grid, i made function but it works only on 1st row of grid and calculate total of first row of grid and then show this value in grand total textbox too. I want to do the same on all 4 rows of grid, what do i do? Kindly help.
        function CalculateTotal() {
                var Gtot = 0;

```
            var RowCount = 0;
            //var RowCount = document.getElementById('<%= hfGrdRows.ClientID%>').value - 0;
            //alert(RowCount);
            var grid = document.getElementById('<%= Grd_Exams.ClientID%>');
            for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length ; i++) {

                    var cell = grid.rows[i].cells;
                    //var HTML = cell[0].innerHTML;

                        var Participation = document.getElementById('txtCl_Part').value - 0;

                        var Assgnmnt = document.getElementById('txtAssgnmnt').value - 0;
                        var Quiz = document.getElementById('txtQuiz').value - 0;
                        var WrPaper = document.getElementById('txtWP').value - 0;
                        var OSME = document.getElementById('txtOSME').value - 0;
                        //for (var i = 1; i < grdLength - 1; i++) {

                        var Total = parseFloat(Participation) + parseFloat(Assgnmnt) + parseFloat(Quiz) + parseFloat(WrPaper) + parseFloat(OSME);
                        if (!isNaN(Total)) {
                            document.getElementById('txtTotal').value = Total;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Nikal");
                        }
                    }
                var getTotal = document.getElementById('txtTotal').value - 0;
                var Gtot = parseInt(Gtot) + parseFloat(getTotal);
                if (!isNaN(Gtot)) {
                    document.getElementById('txtGTot').value = Gtot;
                }

                else {
                    alert("Cannot Show Total");
                }

                var Percentage = (parseFloat(Gtot) * 100) / 400;

                if (!isNaN(Percentage)) {
                    document.getElementById('txtPercent').value = Percentage;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Cannot show percentage");
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Gridview is just a table

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
 for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
 //row
 for (var x = 0, col; col = row.cells[x]; x++) {
 // column & column cell
  if (x===0) {
  //first column
  var cell = row.cells[x];
 // do something with cell
    }
  }  
 }
```

Comment: could you please guide me in more detail?